# Paragraph width don't change. text-align: justify;

Tags: html, css

I want my paragraph of text to be about 800px, and when i make the browser width smaller i want to avoid the use of the bottom scroll bar, i achieve the 800px width with this markup:

CSS

```
.center-justified { 
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}
```

HTML

```
<p class="center-justified"> Lot of Text </p>
```

But the paragraph of text, doesn't flow when i change the browser width.

The other method i use it makes the paragraph of text to flow when i make the browser width smaller, but i can't make it 800px, it uses the whole page.

My markup, CSS

```
p.center { text-align: center; text-align: justify; }
```

Html

```
<p class="center"> Lot of Text </p>
```

And if i use just a `<p> Lot of Text </p>` has the same output as above.

Here is the whole markup i use: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ65L/)

Comment: What is the question? Do you want a hidden scroll bar? Do you want the width of the paragraph to grow and shrink with the browser?

Comment: Yes i did not described my problem very well, i wanted the width of the paragraph to grow and shrink with the browser. MarkkNijboer's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221111/paragraph-width-dont-change-text-align-justify?answertab=votes#tab-top)  solved the issue i had.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set your maximum width to 800px. You will be able to get 800px width if possible else it will take the maximum space it can take.

```
.center-justified { 
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ65L/1/)**

Comment: MarkkNijboer Thank you very much, my problem has solved, i used the width: 800 previously with no luck but the  `margin: 0 auto;` made the difference. Krishanu Dey thank you too for the demo link.